# Add Column to DataGridView with dynamic calculations

Tags: c#, datagridview

Is there any possibility to add a column to a `DataGridView` to dynamic calculate values?

I have a `DataGridView` populated by a `LINQ` query (ToList). I'm using `EF6` (Database first).

I need to add one column not binded to query collection that calculates the days between 2 dates.

Here's my `DataGridView` populate list:

```
public class Recl
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Concelho { get; set; }
        public string Entidade { get; set; }
        public string LC { get; set; }
        public string Classificacao { get; set; }
        public string TipoR { get; set; }
        public string TipoE { get; set; }
        public string Identificador { get; set; }
        public string Estado { get; set; }
        public decimal? Custos { get; set; }
        public string Descricao { get; set; }
        public DateTime DataR { get; set; }
        public DateTime DataE { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DataRespostaEE { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DataRespostaC { get; set; }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Recl> LoadData()
    {
        var ctx = new IWMJEntities();
        var fillrecl = (from p in ctx.tblRecl.AsQueryable()
                         join c in ctx.tblConc on p.ConcID equals c.ConcID
                         join e in ctx.tblEnt on p.EntID equals e.EntID
                         join ex in ctx.tblLC on p.LCID equals ex.LCID
                         join cl in ctx.tblClassificacao on p.ClassificacaoID equals cl.ClassificacaoID
                        join tp in ctx.tblTipoR on p.TipoRID equals tp.TipoRID
                        join te in ctx.tblTipoE on p.TipoEID equals te.TipoEID
                        select new Recl
                        {
                             ID = p.ReclID,
                             Concelho = c.NomeConcelho,
                             Entidade = e.Nome,
                             LC = ex.Codigo,
                             Classificacao = cl.Classificacao,
                             TipoR = tp.TipoR,
                             TipoE = te.TipoE,
                             Identificador = p.Identificador,
                             Estado = p.Estado,
                             Custos = p.Custos,
                             DataR = p.DataR,
                             DataE = p.DataE,
                             DataRespostaEE = p.DataRespostaEmpresa,
                             DataRespostaCliente = p.DataRespostaCliente
                         }).ToList();
        return fillrecl;
    }
```

And the call to load `DataGridView` from Load Event:

```
datagrid.DataSource = LoadData();
```

How can I add one more column (Days) which calculate diference in Days between `DateTime.Now` and `DataE`?

Where do I put this new column on code?

Answer (score 0):

Add a property (say `DifferenceInDays`) to `Recl` class and in your `select` clause add `DifferenceInDays = (DateTime.Now - p.DataE).Days`

Comment: Thanks, but a simple subtraction of dates gives error of DbArithmeticExpression arguments. So I added a property to Recl class "Days" and in select query I used (int) DbFunctions.DiffDays(p.DataE, DateTime.Now). This works great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a property to your class:

```
public class Recl
{
    ...    
    public DateTime DataE { get; set; }

    public TimeSpan DaysDifference { get { return DateTime.Now - DataE; } }
}
```